# Problems pre-sorting xml prior to transforming

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

Using another code example on stackoverflow we've got a paginated print report with headers and footers (yes, that old chestnut) working nicely, doing something like this (where RESULTS_ROW has got multiple child nodes):

```
<xsl:variable name="n" select="number(4)"/>

<xsl:template match="RESULTS">
<body>
<div id="page">
  <output>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="RESULTS_ROW"/>
  </output>
</div>      
</body>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="RESULTS_ROW">              
    <p/>
        [HTML FOR PAGE START]
        <br/>
    <xsl:for-each select=". | following-sibling::RESULTS_ROW[position() &lt; $n]">
        <xsl:value-of select="ITEM43"/><!--Lots more goes in here -->
            <br/>
    </xsl:for-each>
    [HTML FOR PAGE END]
        <p/>
</xsl:template>
```

The problem came with the need to sort RESULTS_ROW on one of its child node values (ITEM43) *before* the transformation into lumps of 4 elements takes place otherwise the sorting doesn't take account of all child nodes.

The output is currently something like

```
[HTML FOR PAGE START]
North
West
North
River
[HTML FOR PAGE END]

[HTML FOR PAGE START]
West
North
River
North
[HTML FOR PAGE END]
```

Whereas I want the nodes to be completed sorted before they're split into groups, something like:

```
[HTML FOR PAGE START]
North
North
North
North
[HTML FOR PAGE END]

[HTML FOR PAGE START]
River    
River    
West
West
[HTML FOR PAGE END]
```

I've tried everything my not very capable XSL brain can think of but all kinds of sorting, using modes to apply multiple templates to the same node, copying, creating variables containing nodal values etc - nothing seems to work.

Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: Can you please show an example of the XML input?

Comment: @DevNull The XML's really flat and quite straightforward: `<PROP_INFO>  
 <RESULTS>  
  <RESULTS_ROW num="1">  
   <LABEL43>Area</LABEL43>  
   <ITEM43>Northern</ITEM43>  
  </RESULTS_ROW>  
    
  <RESULTS_ROW num="2">  
   <LABEL43>Area</LABEL43>  
   <ITEM43>West</ITEM43>  
  </RESULTS_ROW>  
     
  <RESULTS_ROW num="3">  
   <LABEL43>Area</LABEL43>  
   <ITEM43>North</ITEM43>  
  </RESULTS_ROW>  
 </RESULTS>  
</PROP_INFO>`   with lots more nodes other than item43 and label43 at the same level which I've left out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDIT** Right, after a bit of determination and checking exactly what `following-sibling` does I think I've got your solution:

`following-sibling` will always process from the original document, not the order you may have it currently sorted in. This means that when you print out the next 4 nodes, it is taking the next 4 nodes in the original document and not conforming to the sort order.

What you need to do is sort the node list before applying your 4 row template (See code sample below).

This now populates the variable `SortedResults` with a string containing a new document, sorted as required. By using the `node-set()` you can then convert this back into XML and then apply a template.

There is one more problem in your original `RESULTS` template that affected your results. You were calling `apply-templates` over every row so were outputting the next four siblings after each row in the document. This can be resolved with the mod operator shown previously to ensure that the results are only output for every fourth row.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"  xmlns:exslt="http://exslt.org/common" extension-element-prefixes="exslt">

<xsl:variable name="n" select="number(4)"/>

<xsl:template match="RESULTS">
    <xsl:variable name="SortedResults">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="RESULTS_ROW" mode="sort">
            <xsl:sort select="ITEM43"/>
        </xsl:apply-templates>
    </xsl:variable>

    <xsl:variable name="SortedResultsNodeSet" select="exslt:node-set($SortedResults)" />

    <body>
        <div id="page">
            <output>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="$SortedResultsNodeSet/RESULTS_ROW[position() mod $n = 1]" />
            </output>
        </div>
    </body>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="RESULTS_ROW" mode="sort">
    <xsl:copy-of select="current()"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="RESULTS_ROW">

    <p/>
    [HTML FOR PAGE START]
    <br/>
    <xsl:for-each select=". | following-sibling::RESULTS_ROW[position() &lt; $n]">
        <xsl:value-of select="ITEM43"/>
        <br/>
    </xsl:for-each>
    [HTML FOR PAGE END]
    <p/>

</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Please note the additional namespace that has been added so that the `node-set()` extension method could be used.

Comment: thanks for this. It does indeed work, but sadly my placeholders (i.e [HTML FOR PAGE END] have split html, so a table tag is opened at the top and closed at the bottom and this won't work when they're enclosed in IFs (and I can't think of another way of doing it in XSLT that's well formed). A neat solution yours though, simple but clever. Thanks for taking the time to post.

Comment: @DanH You're right, it's pretty useless for any template html. I have revised my answer after thinking about it again!

Comment: That's excellent and does exactly what we needed. I think you may be some kind of genius ;-)  I knew what I needed to do but a couple of hours of reading didn't even get me close, so thank you. Thanks too for solving the bug which has vastly improved performance (and outcome).I can only begin to understand how you've solved this, but that'll give me something else to read about! You're a star...

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to add `xsl:sort` to your `xsl:apply-templates` for "RESULTS_ROW":

```
  <xsl:template match="RESULTS">
    <body>
      <div id="page">
        <output>
          <xsl:apply-templates select="RESULTS_ROW">
            <xsl:sort select="someElem" data-type="text" order="ascending"/>
          </xsl:apply-templates>
        </output>
      </div>      
    </body>
  </xsl:template>
```

You will need to change the `select` and you might need to change `data-type` and `order` depending on your input and desired output.

Comment: Thanks DevNull, I've tried something similar but this sorts the elements in groups so that each group of 4 is sorted in relation to each other, but within the group of 4 these are still unsorted. What I was trying to achieve was all nodes (text) were sorted before being split into groups of 4.

Comment: So you're actually trying to sort text nodes? An example XML input with an example of the desired output would be very helpful.

Comment: Yeahm thanks @DevNull a better explanation would probably help!

Comment: @DanH - Also, are you using XSLT 1.0 or 2.0?

Comment: I'm using FireFox to transform it, does that answer that?